# Creating my own mathematical function

Tags: functions, wave-equation

I want to model a excitation decay function, with a similar morpholofy as $f(x) = \frac{1}{x}$.

I have the following features that I want my function to comply with. First, I want to control the number of points to become zero, that is, I want to control if the signal goes to zero after $20$ points, or $40$ points, or other size.

In summary, I want the function to start at a maximum of $N$ and decay in a shape similar as$\frac{1}{x}$ and finally becomes zero after $M$ points.

More info:

- the function is define from [0, M].
- The global maximum is at 0, and the minimum is at M, where at M the signal is zero.
  from 0 and above the signal is zero.

How could I design such a function?

Comment: How "pointy"/steep is it at 0? Ie. what do you want the value of its derivative to be at 0? It could be anything from $-\infty$ to 0.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  It might be helpful to explain some terms in your question like what is an "excitation function decay" and what is meant by "morpholofy".

Comment: If your function becomes $0$ at some finite $x$, how would you like it to behave beyond that?

Comment: keeping the value at zero

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure if you want it to almost completely flatten before it goes to zero, but with the information you gave, I assume you could use a rational function that has an $x$ intercept at $M$ and a $y$ intercept at $N$. The function would be:

$$
f(x) = \frac{M-x}{x + \frac{M}{N}}
$$

This is a function that generates a graph that looks like $y=\frac{1}{x}$ and has an $x$ intercept at $M$ and a $y$ intercept at $N$. Just change $M$ and $N$ to the values you want.

Comment: I have plotted the function in python. It looks like M defines the zerocrossing but and N is 20, which is the value at x=0. Besides, the function goes down zero after x = 20.
Hope you can see it here:
https://app.gemoo.com/share/image-annotation/573749372561342464?codeId=M0Gk590BVXBna&origin=imageurlgenerator
Maybe I can make it as a function defined in sections for x<M it is the function you provided and x>M, output a zero

Comment: @GGChe I think what you're saying is you want the function to reach $0$ at $x=M$ and then stay $0$ if I'm not mistaken. If that is the case, I can't think of a function that would match that and look like $y=\frac{1}{x}$ other than a piecewise function.

Comment: you are right. I was doing some research and I foundthat exponential decay might fit better the kind of funcion I am looking for. but I dont know how to control the K parameter and the x that touches zero. I will try to do some review about this.